# sbt is installed but not found

Tags: scala, path, sbt, dnf

Fedora 25.  sbt is installed and I have been using it, probably last time was a week ago.  But today it is not found.

```
$ sbt
bash: sbt: command not found...
Install package 'sbt' to provide command 'sbt'? [N/y]
```

Tried a reinstall but dnf knows what I do

```
$ sudo dnf install sbt
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:31:12 ago on Thu Apr 27 19:39:34 2017.
Package sbt-0.13.15.2-2.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Checked for install location with which but no luck

```
$ which sbt
/usr/bin/which: no sbt in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/xxx/.local/bin:/home/xxx/bin)
```

I would guess the problem is in my $PATH however I have not altered it, although I have installed some packages

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/xxx/.local/bin:/home/xxx/bin
```

Finally i did find a jar named sbt-launch.jar in /usr/share/sbt/bin/ but I don't think /usr/share has ever been part of my $PATH.

Recommendations? thx

Answer (score 3):

fixed it by running

$dnf reinstall sbt

Out of curiosity I checked $PATH again afterwards and it was the same. So it was something else evidently.

Comment: in CentOS `yum reinstall sbt` fixed it, though I had to update java version afterwords due to incompatible versions between java7 and java8

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it reinstalling:

First, uninstall sbt:

> yum remove sbt

Then download the version you want from https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/

> wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-0.13.16.rpm

And install by yum

> sudo yum install sbt-0.13.16.rpm

Check it with sbt about

> sbt about

It must show you similar to

sbt about

[info] This is sbt 0.13.16
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.6